# Unable to add state variable to a state array on submit in React

Tags: reactjs

I've just completed a youtube video on react and am trying to practice with no guides. I want to make a simple to-do app (yes I'm doing it all in one component first then I plan to break it out).
However I am stuck at something simple but I want to understand why.

I am currently trying to update my state array "list" when the submit button is clicked. This calls the handleSubmit function where I am trying to unshift the "inputData" state variable into the "prevList". It works like a charm the first time, but then on the second run it crashes. Is my list variable somehow changing from an array to a string or object?

The error is p.jsx:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unshift')

```
import React from "react";

import "./App.css";

export default function App() {
  const [inputData, setInputData] = React.useState("");
  const [list, setList] = React.useState([]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const value = event.target.value;
    setInputData(() => value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setList((prevList) => {
      prevList.unshift(inputData);
      console.log(prevList);
      setInputData("");
    });
  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div>
        <h1>TO DO LIST</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
        <form>
          <input type="text" value={inputData} onChange={handleChange} />
          <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Item</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3>Example Task</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: When you do a [functional update](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state) you have to return the new value. Also **never** mutate a value held in state.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, In the second part of your comment are you referring to the line setInputData("")?

Comment: No, that's not mutating a value (strings aren't mutable, and that's a new value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unshift')**" occurs because the prevList parameter of the setList function is not defined when trying to access the unshift method on it. This is likely because the setList function is not correctly updating the state of the list variable.
It will fix the undefined issue.

```
 function handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      setList((prevList) => {
        if (prevList) {
          prevList.unshift(inputData);
          console.log(prevList);
          setInputData("");
          return prevList;
        } else {
          return [inputData];
        }
      });
    }
```